# Django How to escape special character and use slice method in HTML template for json data

Tags: javascript, json, python-3.x, django

before applying json method I was using this `{{filt.body|striptags|safe|slice:":250" }}` in my html template  for escape all special character. Now my data loading from json and how to apply above method in my html template.

**models.py**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
       body = RichTextUploadingField()
```

views.py

```
class PostJsonListView(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):

        posts = list(Blog.objects.all().filter(is_published='published') )
        data = list()
        for i in posts:
            data.append({'body':i.body})
            
          
       
        return JsonResponse({'data':data},safe=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in your view like this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import SafeString
from django.utils.html import strip_tags

for i in posts:
   body = strip_tags(SafeString(i.body))[:250]
   data.append({'body':  body})
```

Comment: Ahtisham it will not work because  PostJsonListView not rendering any html page. I am using PostJsonListView only for getting json data and I am using ajax in my html.

Comment: Updated the answer check

Comment: You can mark it as accepted if it fixed your issue :)

Comment: Ahtisham definitely I will accept. I am trying to fix the issue

Comment: Ahtisham can you tell me how to import safe tag in views? normally we use it in html like this `{{ blog.description|safe }}`

Comment: use `from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`

Comment: is there any documentation available for learn about those tag. Specially how to import theme in views? we know how to use theme in html but it will be helpful if you have any  documentation link how to import those tag in views

Comment: I just told you already you can use it like normal function `mark_safe(your_html)` docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#filters-and-auto-escaping